# How can I copy one worksheet from an open workbook to a closed workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that opens to a form the user scans a barcode, and the form closes and closes Excel.

I want to copy one sheet ("STOREDATA") in the open workbook (scanner.xlsm) before it closes, to a closed workbook(REPORT.xlsx) in same directory. It doesn't matter if it opens the closed workbook as long as it closes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a pretty simple task.

Open the workbook, make the copy, save it, then close it.

```
Sub copySheetToReport()

    With Application.Workbooks.Open("REPORT.xlsx")

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STOREDATA").Copy after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Save
        .Close

     End With

End Sub
```

This will place the copied worksheet at the very end.

Comment: i have a problem now... the way this app works is the click the icon to scan a barcode a form opens and they scan the code and the form closes and excel closes. Now i get the first workbook opens a form opens the operator scans the barcode, the REPORT wb gets updated. then report wb  closes,  then the form closes(scan form) then the original workbook closes BUT leaving a blank excel with no sheets running and maximized. i just called that code from a module. right after the first worksheet in the original workbook updates. im puzzled by this.. any thoughts ?

Comment: Nothing should have happened with the original workbook. Perhaps try a `ThisWorkbook.Activate` and/or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STOREDATA").Activate` after the `End With` line.